# How do I get the attached element from the elements attached plugin data method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jquery plugin and I am stuck trying to figure out how to get the element that the current method execution is being called from.

This is a basic version of what I am doing..

**I have some form inputs:**

```
<input class="myInput" id="txtInput1" type="text" />
<input class="myInput" id="txtInput2" type="text" />
<input class="myInput" id="txtInput3" type="text" />
```

**I have this plugin:**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myplugin=function(options) {
        options=$.extend({
            opt1: 'val1',
            etc: ''
        }, options);

        function example() {
            // 'this' in here is the data-myplugin value of the element that called this method.

            // ---------------------------------------------------------
            //
            // How do I determine which element is calling this method ?
            //
            // eg: in this example how do I know it is the $('#input2') element ?  
            //
            // ---------------------------------------------------------
        }

        this.each(function() {            

            // in this example -- loops through each of the form input elements
            // .. manipulate the DOM

        }).data('myplugin', { 
            // .. adds data-myplugin to each of the form elements in the loop with a value that is our plugin object which contains our example() method and options
            example: example,            
            options: options
        });

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**I instantiate the plugin like this:**

```
$('.myInput').myplugin();
```

**I call the example() plugin method like this:**

```
$('#input2').data('myplugin').example();
```

**I am trying to avoid having to pass it in as a parameter, eg:**

```
// I don't want to have to do this if I don't have to:
$('#input2').data('myplugin').example('input2');
```

Comment: *"adds data-myplugin to each of the form elements..."* No, it doesn't. It attaches to the internal data cache jQuery maintains for the element, which is not a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Does it matter that $('x').data('something')="stuff" <> <x data-something="stuff"> if how you access either with jquery are the same?  But we digress.

Comment: It matters when people think it sets `data-*` attributes (and many do) and then wonder why it doesn't work when they're interacting with things like Bootstrap that use the `data-*` attributes (and not `data`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this design is highly problematic because of jQuery's set-based nature, which leads to exactly the problem you're having (and is why you don't see it used much). Consider this:

```
<div id="first"  class="a c"></div>
<div id="second" class="b c"></div>
```

Then the code:

```
$(".a").myplugin({option: 1});
$(".b").myplugin({option: 2});
$(".c").data("myplugin").example();
```

The author clearly intends to use your `example` function on all of the elements matching `.c`, but the `data` function will only return your data object for the *first* of those elements, initialized with `option: 1` (this is how jQuery's accessor work in general: setting sets on all elements in the set, getting gets only from the first element in the set). There's nothing you can do when creating your data object that will solve that.

Instead, a plugin should assume it will get called for various different sets, and work in each case on the information specific to each element in that set.

To do that, follow the well-established pattern of making your plugin function both the initializer (accepting an object with options) *and* the method dispatch (accepting a string with the command name):

```
$(".a").myplugin({option: 1});
$(".b").myplugin({option: 2});
$(".c").myplugin("example");
```

Now, within `myplugin`, you can happily loop through the `".c"` set and use the options stored on each element in it, which will vary (some will be `option: 1`, others will be `option: 2`).

Here's a simple, but complete, example doing the above (see comments):

```js
(function($) {
    // A map of our methods
    var methods = Object.create(null);

    // Default options
    var defaultOptions = {
        color: "red",
        fontSize: "16px"
    };

    // Methods

    methods.color = function color(set, args) {
        // Loop over the elements, using the options specific to each element
        // Return the set for chaining
        return set.each(function() {
            var info = methodEntry(this);
            info.$element.css("color", info.options.color);
        });
    };

    methods.fontSize = function fontSize(set, args) {
        return set.each(function() {
            var info = methodEntry(this);
            info.$element.css("font-size", info.options.fontSize);
        });
    };

    methods.getColor = function getColor(set, args) {
        // Getters only access the first element...
        var info = methodEntry(set[0]);
        // ...and return something other than the set
        return info.options.color;
    }

    // init
    
    function init(set, args) {
        return set.data("myplugin", $.extend({}, defaultOptions, args[0]));
    }

    // plumbing

    function methodEntry(element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var options = $element.data("myplugin");
        if (!options) {
            throw new Error("myplugin not initialized for element");
        }
        return {$element: $element, options: options};
    }

    // Plugin function

    $.fn.myplugin = function(methodName) {
        var isMethodCall = typeof methodName === "string";
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, isMethodCall ? 1 : 0);
        var method = isMethodCall ? methods[methodName] : init;
        if (!method) {
            throw new Error("myplugin has no method called '" + arg + "'");
        }
        return method(this, args);
    };
})(jQuery);

// Using it
$(".a").myplugin({color: "green"});
$(".b").myplugin({color: "blue", fontSize: "20px"});
$(".c").myplugin("color").myplugin("fontSize"); // Note chainging works
console.log($(".c").myplugin("getColor"));      // "green" because the *first* element's setting is green
```

```html
<div id="first"  class="a c">first</div>
<div id="second" class="b c">second</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternately, you can do the same sort of thing using `myplugin()`, itself, in place of your `data("myplugin")`:

```
$(".a").myplugin({option: 1});
$(".b").myplugin({option: 2});
$(".c").myplugin().example();
```

You'd have `myplugin` respond to a call without options by returning an object with your methods on it and a reference to the set to call the method on:

```
return {
    elements: this,
    example: ...
}
```

The methods would then use `this.elements` to get the elements to act on. I won't do up a full example, but it's fairly straightforward to adapt it if you prefer that syntax.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem with the internet is that you can find lots of resources that each say they are the standard boilerplate to use, as is the case for the template I was using.  I will switch over to the example you have provided.

Comment: @Drew - True that, I've seen *several* "standard jQuery plugin" templates that were...um...not ideal. :-) (And others that were basically the above, which is probably where I learned it.)

Comment: Using your code snippet above, in the methods, info.$element is always an indexed object so I have to use info.$element[0].css('etc'); in order for the example to work.

Comment: @Drew - Yes, it's always a jQuery object (set). That's just for convenience (using jQuery methods), the set always has just one element in it. No, `info.$element[0].css('etc')` isn't necessary, and in fact won't work: DOM elements don't have a `css` function. jQuery objects do. You'd just use `info.$element.css('etc')` as the live example above does.